# How to handle values greater than 9 with ascii values in c++

Tags: c++, char, ascii

I know that when the numbers range between 1 and 9 you must do the following to convert a int into a char character:

for eg.

```
char _val = val + '0';
```

My question is how do you do it with values greater than 9 in the above format?

Comment: Well you're going to need two ascii characters, aren't you? Sounds like a job for some if's. Or a loop with `%10` and `/10` if you get clever.

Comment: It seems you look for the `itoa` function?

Comment: [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Comment: @martin, `itoa` isn't a standard C++ function.

Comment: @chris yes, that's true, and it's the opposite of what is asked, I should read more carefully, so the appropriate non-standard function is `atoi`

Comment: There are no "values greater than 9 in the above format". Valid digits are between '0' and '9'.

Comment: Please do not forget the zero - making it a range [0, 9]

Comment: Like such?  stringstream _val; _val << val;

Comment: Something like that, but please just avoid leading `_`.

Comment: @martin, We're going int -> string here, so it would be `itoa`, but `atoi`, although bad, is at least standard. For `itoa` in C, there's `snprintf`.

Comment: For exercise you might take advantage of modulo (to get the last decimal digit) and division by ten (to remove that digit) in a loop.

Comment: @chris, ok, I have just confused myself, thanks for the hint ... .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have c++11 I would say use `std::to_string` as noted in the comments. If you have an older compiler, I suggest `boost::lexical_cast` or if you can't use boost, then use a `std::ostringstream`.